# Finding line number of first match after given line number

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script to delete multiple lines in an ini file. I have an ini file configured in the following manner.

```
# There could be any text before the following text

[machine1.conn]
ipAddress=192.168.1.1
portNumber=11001

[machine2.conn]
ipAddress=192.168.1.2
portNumber=11002

[machine3.conn]
ipAddress=192.168.1.3
portNumber=11003

# There could be any text after the previous text
```

I would like to delete all of these entries from the ini file (attributes included).

There could be any number of "machine" entries in the ini file but for this example I show only 3. The bracketed labels are completely unique in the ini file but the attributes following each are obviously not. I already have a method for determining the line numbers of the first `[machine#.conn]` as well as the last; let's say these are assigned to variables `$firstMachineLineNum` and `$lastMachineLineNum` respectively. What I was going to do was use sed to delete a range of lines from `$firstMachineLineNum` to the last machine's `portNumber` line number. I was going in this sort of direction, `sed -i '$firstMachineLineNum,$lastMachinesPortNumLineNum$d' file.ini`. To do this, I need a method for determining `$lastMachinesPortNumLineNum`, in other words, the line number of the first match of `portNumber` AFTER the last `[machine#.conn]` (which in my example is `[machine3.conn]`). I would ideally not have to rely on just adding 2 to `$lastMachineLineNum`.

How could I best extract this line number using sed and/or grep?  Am I making this too complicated in general and there is a much simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed will do it easily enough if the file is as shown (no blank lines within a block you want to remove):

```
sed '/^\[machine[0-9]\{1,\}\.conn\]/,/^\s*$/d' file
```

Modified to accept any name ending in .conn:

```
sed '/^\[.*\.conn\]/,/^\s*$/d' file
```

Modified for variable target line:

```
machine='machine1'
sed '/^\['"$machine"'\.conn\]/,/^\s*$/d' file
```

Comment: Would you mind rewriting that so that the machine title can be anything, and only the `.conn` is static? It seems like `sed '/^\[.*.\{1,\}\conn]/,/^\s*$/d' file.ini` works ok (I also added a `^` to ensure it's matching at the beginning of the lines). Do I have this correct or do I have a dot in the wrong place?

Comment: Edited - at first I thought you meant use a variable for the machine name, but then I re-read your comment. I put in both. (Your version removed the '\' from the '.' so it no longer meant a period and would match any characters, 1 or more times.)

Answer (score 1):

try this one-liner:

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '!/machine[0-9]+\.conn/' file
```

small test:

```
kent$  cat file
[foo_keep]
foo=foo

[machine1.conn]
ipAddress=192.168.1.1
portNumber=11001

[machine2.conn]
ipAddress=192.168.1.2
portNumber=11002

[machine3.conn]
ipAddress=192.168.1.3
portNumber=11003

[bar_keep]
bar=bar

[machine4.conn]
ipAddress=whatever
portNumber=11001

[machine5.conn]
ipAddress=whatever
portNumber=11002

[baz_keep]
hhh=hhh
```

output

```
kent$   awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '!/machine[0-9]+\.conn/' file
[foo_keep]
foo=foo

[bar_keep]
bar=bar

[baz_keep]
hhh=hhh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exclude just this specific block you can use this:

```
awk 'NR < $firstline || NR > $lastline {print $0}' file.txt
```